# Getting typeerror on Event property

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I'm trying to target an event but I'm getting error, what I have tried was

```
  public gotoPage(event: Event): void {
    const gettest = (event.target as HTMLElement)?.getAttribute('href');
    if (href) {
      const testModule = "value1"
      if (ssoModule) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML :

```
<ion-card-content>
  <ion-item class="no-padding" (click)="gotoPage($event)">
    <div>
{{test}}
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card-content>
```

But I'm getting error as

```
Property 'target' does not exist on type 'Event_2'.
Property 'target' does not exist on type 'RouterEvent'.
Property 'preventDefault' does not exist on type 'Event_2'.
Property 'preventDefault' does not exist on type 'RouterEvent'.
```

Right now I'm using type as any which solves the error but I want to rectify this error, any solution ?

Comment: Are you using the right `Event` type? I tested your function in a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQR21N) with no errors.

Comment: That's what I can't able to figure out that's why i asked this question,

Comment: Well, right now the code you provided doesn't give any infication as to where the problem is. Could you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Preferably in an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)

Comment: Would it be okay to add MouseEvent instead of the type Event?

Answer (score 0):

Check maybe your Event type was imported from somewhere else?